For some reason my uri is not saved normally
I save the URI and then write it into the database with other data, but for some reason it starts to look different. Here's an example:
[1] https://i.sstatic.net/WXsIm.png
But when I load something like this:
[2] https://i.sstatic.net/fVqAv.png
This is what I get normally:
[3] https://i.sstatic.net/EtdJA.png
My code
private void uploadImageFst(){
    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable) fst.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] byteArr=baos.toByteArray();
    StorageReference mRef=mStorage.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"deal_image");
    UploadTask up=mRef.putBytes(byteArr);
    Task<Uri> task=up.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            return mRef.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            while(!task.isComplete());
            Uri url = task.getResult();
            uploadUriFirst=url;
        }
    });
}

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

String emailik=getIntent().getStringExtra("EmailUser").toString();
rootRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(emailik).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
            User user=ds.getValue(User.class);
            Deal newDeal;
            newDeal = new Deal(getIntent().getStringExtra("EmailUser"), Name.getText().toString(),
                    Author.getText().toString(),
                    Gangrene.getText().toString(), Script.getText().toString(), Price.getText().toString(), uploadUriFirst.toString() ,uploadUriSecond.toString(),uploadUriThird.toString(),
                    StateExchange,user.Adress);
            DatabaseReference mDataBaseDeal =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Deal");
            mDataBaseDeal.push().setValue(newDeal);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Объявление добавлено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});

But when I load something like this:

This is what I get normally:

